# OpenJPA String as date attribute

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I have a Query to parse on JPA , some errors have happened . I want a right way to make this.

Original:

```
Query q = this.em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.codigo = :codigo ORDER BY e.data ASC");
```

My solution but doesn't work:

```
Query q = this.em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Entity  e WHERE e.codigo = :codigo ORDER BY to_date(e.data,'DD/MM/YYYY') ASC");
```

where e.data is a String like "01/01/2014"

Comment: My DB is Oracle Database

Comment: "to_date" is not valid JPQL. http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_query.html

Comment: So, what i do that is similar ?

Comment: JPA 2.1 has "FUNCTION(funcName, args)". Sadly for you, you're using OpenJPA which is using an outdated version of JPA. Many other JPA implementations provide support for "FUNCTION", such as DataNucleus JPA which I use

Comment: I´ll take a look on DataNucleus,  but have some production apps running wiht OpenJPA ,  can´t change this :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I´d replaced it with a nativeQuery.

Then a had be able to use Oracle Date Function